# delete button visible while checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, checkbox

I have table with 3 columns. The third columns is a check box for each row.

```
<tr id='sub".$this->getHtmlId()."_".$cpt."' class='mui-row'>
  <td class='mui-col-md-6'>".$row[0]."</td>
  <td class='mui-col-md-2'>".$row[1]."</td>
  <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
    <component id='box' class=\ "CheckBoxComponent\" name=\ "chk".$row[3]. "\" />
  </td>
</tr>";
```

what i want is that when I check a checkbox the delete button become visible and if i check a second or more it stay visible because I can delete multiple rows at the same time.

Right now, everything I have tried do that when I check a row the button appear I click a second one it disappear and when I click a third one it appear again

here some example that I tried :

```
$('#deleteButton').toggle('slow', function() {
  // Animation complete.
});

var chkbox = $(\".check\");
    button = $(\"#box\");
      button.attr(\"disabled\",\"disabled\");
        chkbox.change(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
              button.removeAttr(\"disabled\");
              }
              else {
                button.attr(\"disabled\",\"disabled\");
                }
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count of checked checkbox by `$(".check:checked").length`

If there is a checked checkbox, show the button.

```js
$(function() {
  //hide on init
  $("#deleteButton").hide();

  $(".check").click(function() {
    //get the number of checked 
    if ($(".check:checked").length) $("#deleteButton").show();
    else $("#deleteButton").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'>1</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'>1</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'>2</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'>2</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='mui-row'>
    <td class='mui-col-md-6'>3</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2'>3</td>
    <td class='mui-col-md-2' style='border:none'>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="deleteButton" type="button">Delete!</button>
```

Comment: It works exactly how I want !! Thank you very much !! :)